# Google Cloud OIDC Gitlab pipeline Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, openid-connect, cicd

I am using Google Cloud OIDC to authenticate with GitLab CICD and trying to list buckets.

```
Authentication => DONE
```

but not able to list resources.

I have attached custom permissions with those service accounts.

[image: CustomRole]

Also,

[image]

Still getting error in GitLab like below,

[image]

Any suggestion what i missed or need to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have added command to set project with command,

```
gcloud config set project xxxx

gcloud storage ls
```

Its done...